# System of equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

Choose the correct(s):
 $A_{m*n}$ , $B_{m*n}$ and $X_{n*1}$ are matrices with real entries.

A) If $AX=O$, $\forall X$ , then $A=O$ (here $O$ represents zero matrix.)

B) $AX=BX$, $\forall X$  , if $A=B$.

C) $AX=BX, \forall X$ , only if $A=B$.

D)  If $A_{n*n}$ and $X_{n*1}$ , then $AX=O$ and $A'X=O$ are of same nature in terms of trivial and non trivial solutions.

I found that D is true as $\rho(A)=\rho(A')$ so their homogeneous systems are of same nature. But I'm confuse for A,B,C.

EDIT ($1$):$A'$ is transpose of matrix $A$ and $\rho(A)$ is rank of $A$.

Comment: $A'$ is transpose of matrix $A$ and $\rho(A)$ is rank of $A$.

Comment: I think $D$ is about homogeneous systems of $AX$ and $A'X$.

Comment: This question was asked in my mid-semester exam. I was thinking it should be from Friedberg but I didn't find it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A)$\forall X,\ AX=0 \rightarrow A=0$

*Proof:*

The hypotesis tells us that $\ker(A)=n$. Thus, using rank's theorem: $\rho(A)=0$, which is true iff $A=0$

B)$A=B\rightarrow \forall X,\ AX=BX$

*Proof:*

$\begin{align}
(A-B)X=0X=0\\
AX-BX=0\\
AX=BX
\end{align}$

C)$\forall X,\ AX=BX \iff A=B$

*Proof:*

We have already proved half of the statement in B). It remains to show only the if part:

$\begin{align}
AX=BX\ \forall  X\\
(A-B)X=0\ \forall  X\
\end{align}$

Thus the matrix $A-B$ satisfies the hypotesis of A), and thus $A-B=0$, and the statement is proved

Comment: thanks a lot....